# Turn to lowercase using SPARQL replace

Tags: sparql

Hi I'm trying to simply write a function that lowercase some of the letter of a string, but without success.

Here is what I wrote:

```
SELECT * 

WHERE {

    BIND (REPLACE ("HELLO", "L",  LCASE("$0") ) AS ?var)

}
```

I get back "`HELLO`".

I followed the spec here https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace for the "`$x`".

However if I write

```
SELECT * 

WHERE {

    BIND (REPLACE ("HELLO", "L",  LCASE("$0HI") ) AS ?var)

}
```

I get back "`HELhiLhiO`".

Why the `LCASE` can't be applied to `$x`?

Comment: If you write `REPLACE ("HELLO", "L",  LCASE("$0HI")`, first `LCASE("$0HI")` turns `"$0HI"` into `"$0hi"`, then it will be executed `REPLACE ("HELLO", "L",  "$0hi")`, obtaining `HELhiLhiO`.

Comment: Thank you yes. Although I figured, so there is no way to do what I want to do in standard sparql ? Need extensions ?

Comment: why can't you use the lower case letter directly? Or is your example just simplified here? What is the real regex if so?

Comment: Yes it is a simplification, as I was trying to figure out if I could implement camelCase and pascalCase is sparql directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LCASE` is applied to the string, then the result is passed to the `REPLACE` function, just like writing "function(1+2)" -- the function get passed 3,not `1+2`.

So LCASE is not applied to the value of `$0` but to the string "$0".

`LCASE("$0HI")` is "$0hi".

The `REPLACE` executes as:

```
REPLACE ("HELLO", "L", "$0hi")
```

and each "L" is replaced by "$0hi" with $0 being substituted for "L".

Comment: Thanks  for the feedback on this. I suspect that I need sparql extension to do this kind of manipulation ?